# Grouping Similar Strings

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm trying to analyze a bunch of search terms, so many that individually they don't tell much.  That said, I'd like to group the terms because I think similar terms should have similar effectiveness.  For example,

```
Term               Group
NBA Basketball     1
Basketball NBA     1
Basketball         1
Baseball           2
```

It's a contrived example, but hopefully it explains what I'm trying to do.  So then, what is the best way to do what I've described?  I thought the `nltk` may have something along those lines, but I'm only barely familiar with it.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to define your problem more - and that requires more knowledge. Try searching on "cluster analysis". NLTK will come in useful when you need to do things like stemming to pre-process the words.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to cluster these terms, and for the similarity metric I recommend [Dice's Coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice%27s_coefficient) at the character-gram level. For example, partition the strings into two-letter sequences to compare (term1="NB", "BA", "A ", " B", "Ba"...).

**nltk** appears to provide dice as [nltk.metrics.association.BigramAssocMeasures.dice()](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.metrics.association.BigramAssocMeasures-class.html), but it's simple enough to implement in a way that'll allow tuning. Here's how to compare these strings at the character rather than word level.

```
import sys, operator

def tokenize(s, glen):
  g2 = set()
  for i in xrange(len(s)-(glen-1)):
    g2.add(s[i:i+glen])
  return g2

def dice_grams(g1, g2): return (2.0*len(g1 & g2)) / (len(g1)+len(g2))

def dice(n, s1, s2): return dice_grams(tokenize(s1, n), tokenize(s2, n))

def main():
  GRAM_LEN = 4
  scores = {}
  for i in xrange(1,len(sys.argv)):
    for j in xrange(i+1, len(sys.argv)):
      s1 = sys.argv[i]
      s2 = sys.argv[j]
      score = dice(GRAM_LEN, s1, s2)
      scores[s1+":"+s2] = score
  for item in sorted(scores.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    print item
```

When this program is run with your strings, the following similarity scores are produced:

```
./dice.py "NBA Basketball" "Basketball NBA" "Basketball" "Baseball"

('NBA Basketball:Baseball', 0.125)
('Basketball NBA:Baseball', 0.125)
('Basketball:Baseball', 0.16666666666666666)
('NBA Basketball:Basketball NBA', 0.63636363636363635)
('NBA Basketball:Basketball', 0.77777777777777779)
('Basketball NBA:Basketball', 0.77777777777777779)
```

At least for this example, the margin between the *basketball* and *baseball* terms should be sufficient for clustering them into separate groups. Alternatively you may be able to use the similarity scores more directly in your code with a threshold.