# Algorithm to compare similarity of ideas (as strings)

Tags: algorithm, nlp, artificial-intelligence

Consider an arbitrary text box that records the answer to the question, what do you want to do before you die?

Using a collection of response strings (max length 240), I'd like to somehow sort and group them and count them by idea (which may be just string similarity as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653157/a-better-similarity-ranking-algorithm-for-variable-length-strings)).

1. Is there another or better way to do something like this?
2. *Is this any different* than string similarity?
3. Is this the right question to be asking?

The idea here is to have people write in a text box over and over again, and me to provide a number that describes, generally speaking, that 802 people *wrote approximately the same thing*

Comment: 802 people? you want a single number? or a partition? or a partition that sort of overlaps?

Comment: @ninjagecko thats a great question. Would you choose partitions over a single number? if so, why?

Comment: well it preserves more information, but it would depend what your really trying to do.

Comment: This problem can go as deep as textual entailment (http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Textual_Entailment_Portal) (http://www.nist.gov/tac/2011/RTE/)

Comment: I described a basic but robust way of grouping strings in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8636993/317110

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is much more difficult than string similarity. This is what you need to do at a minimum:

- Perform some text formatting/cleaning tasks like removing punctuations characters and common "stop words"
- Construct a corpus (collection of words with their usage statistics) from the terms that occur answers.
- Calculate a weight for every term.
- Construct a document vector from every answer (each term corresponds to a dimension in a very high dimensional Euclidian space)
- Run a clustering algorithm on document vectors.

Read a good statistical natural language processing book, or search google for good introductions / tutorials (likely terms: **statistical nlp**, **text categorization**, **clustering**) You can probably find some libraries (**weka** or **nltk** comes to mind) depending on the language of your choice but you need to understand the concepts to use the library anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The [Latent Semantic Analysis (LSA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis) might interest you. Here is [a nice introduction](http://www.puffinwarellc.com/index.php/news-and-articles/articles/33-latent-semantic-analysis-tutorial.html?showall=1).

> Latent semantic analysis (LSA) is a technique in natural language processing, in particular in vectorial semantics, of analyzing relationships between a set of documents and the terms they contain by producing a set of concepts related to the documents and terms.
>   [...]

Comment: LSA is a technique to reduce dimensions by merging similar terms with some serious mathematical magic. I think he has a long way to go (first constructing document vectors correctly and then clustering) before even considering to apply LSA in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is very much an open problem in NLP. @Ali's answer describes the idea at a high level, but the part "Construct a document vector for every answer" is the really hard one. There are a few obvious ways of building a document vector from a the vectors of the words it contains. Addition, multiplication and averaging are fast, but they affectively ignore the syntax. `Man bites dog` and `Dog bites man` will have the same representation, but clearly not the same meaning. Google `compositional distributional semantics`- as far as I know, there are people at Universities of Texas, Trento, Oxford, Sussex and at Google working in the area.